# Сетевая программа

Tags: delphi

Пишу сетевую программу. Как отправить команду с клиента на сервер в делфи (и клиент, и сервер на делфи), например, послать команду закрыть окно или вырубить комп. Программа работает по локальной сети.

Comment: Зависит от того какую вы технологию обмена сообщении используете.

И что конкретно у вас не получается?

Answer (score 1):

Можно компонентами ClientSocket,TCPClient

Comment: щас попробую)